# how to retrieve Data in correct encoding from Mysql using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, character-encoding, collation

when I insert data (includes French characters) to my database using the sql insert into it works fine :

```
   CREATE TABLE Categories(code_interne_c varchar(100) primary key,
                           description    varchar(100));

   INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('01','Matières premières');
   INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('02','Articles de conditionnement');
   INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('03','Consommables production');
   INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('04','Produits de nettoyage');
   INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('05','Réactifs');
```

when I use mysql command line it works fine( as you see its the normal and the expected output) too:

```
   mysql> select * from categories;
   +----------------+-------------------------------------------+
   | code_interne_c | description                               |
   +----------------+-------------------------------------------+
   | 01             | Matières premières                        |
   | 02             | Articles de conditionnement               |
   | 03             | Consommables production                   |
   | 04             | Produits de nettoyage                     |
   | 05             | Réactifs                                  |
   +----------------+-------------------------------------------+
   14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when I retrieve Data using  **jdbc** :

```
public static String testreqchar(){
    try {
        Statement st = cx.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from categories");
        rs.next();
        return rs.getString(2)+"|| and  test French accent characters : é ô ê à è û ";
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Methodes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
public static void main(String a[]) {

           System.out.println(testreqchar());
}
```

this is what i get as an output in my IDE and Interfaces :

```
    MatiŠres premiŠres|| and  test French accent characters : é ô ê à è û
```

I don't know what is the problem.

```
   Mysql 5.5.27 set on UTF-8 as charset on Win server 2008 R2 French
   mysql-connector-java-5.1.21
   JDK 1.7 Running on win 7 pro French.
```

Comment: so far i can officially announce that's its not an IDE encoding problem, but its a Mysql or JDBC Problem.

Answer (score 2):

Put `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8` at the end of your connection String. see sample,

```
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection  
        ( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bug_utf8?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8"
```

Comment: @Papa_Jay check your IDE's UTF-8 setting. If your application is web application, you can also check your browser character encoding.

Comment: it's a Java Desktop application and the IDE is Netbeans 7.2, can't find any option where you change the terminals Charset .

Comment: i don't know why this bug has no solution, this is getting on my nerves :s

Comment: and nobody is helping, tries all solutions and techniques and still getting this devilish malformed data representation, the database terminal shows good encoding, but why it is malformed on the application basis :s

Comment: it's not an IDE problem, its either a Mysql bug, or a JDBC problem, check out my post again.

Comment: @Papa_Jay you need to edit /etc/netbeans.conf.Just insert a -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to netbeans_default_options.

Comment: hey, its not an ide problem, it's mysql or jdbc, i set th echarset and everything but it just won't work, why ?